Is it possible to configure Apache Ignite number of backups for IgniteLock, IgniteSemaphore and other distributed structures
I am new to Apache Ignite and exploring use of its distributed structures. I noticed that even with 5 nodes cluster when two nodes are shut down (i think I even observed it with 1 node going down but not sure) the existing locks start failing
Failed to execute the cache operation (all partition owners have left the grid, partition data has been lost) [cacheName=ignite-sys-atomic-cache@default-volatile-ds-group@volatileDsMemPlc
I noticed that the cache is partitioned and has 1 backup. I was looking for any API to configure number of backups for system cache and perhaps ability to make it replicated rather than partitioned as my cluster will not have large volume of data or objects but will be used mostly for distributed queues, locks and semaphores and needs to be rather resilient
I tried to reset lost partition for this cache ignite-sys-atomic-cache@default-volatile-ds-group@volatileDsMemPlc and reacquire Lock with the same name and got Failed to find reentrant lock with given name: myLock
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Failed to find reentrant lock with given name: myLock
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastructures.GridCacheLockImpl$Sync$1.call(GridCacheLockImpl.java:520)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastructures.GridCacheLockImpl$Sync$1.call(GridCacheLockImpl.java:514)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheUtils.retryTopologySafe(GridCacheUtils.java:1396)
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.datastructures.GridCacheLockImpl$Sync.compareAndSetGlobalState(GridCacheLockImpl.java:514)
    ... 11 more

Also are locks/semaphores persistent or they are strictly in-memory?
I would appreciate your advise
Thank you,
Alex
Went over docs and config APIs but could not find any mention of configuring system caches

You can change the default cache configuration for data structures:
        AtomicConfiguration atomicCfg = new AtomicConfiguration()
                .setCacheMode(CacheMode.PARTITIONED)
                .setBackups(3);
        
        IgniteConfiguration igniteCfg = new IgniteConfiguration()
                .setAtomicConfiguration(atomicCfg);

        Ignition.start(igniteCfg);


Thank you Pavel. I tried it yesterday - did not seem to make any difference for Locks. I will try again carefully.
I am also curious if following is a correct behavior for Queues. I would start a cluster of 3 with persistence and it captured baseline topology. then I started 2 server nodes  where I had my experiments. When i list cluster nodes all 5 appeared but queue put/take would work once (say I put but take blocked or if I take all, put would not work in different threads). Only when I set baselineAutoAdjustEnabled(true) and it updated base topology  it started to work as expected
